Deploy .NET 7 class library project with dotnet ef migration
I have a .NET 7 solution with one project being a npgsql layer class library. I need to deploy it with dotnet ef migration tool, but without the .NET Core SDK, in an isolated network.
I'm trying to run this:
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained true

but it returned an error that "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64 cannot be found". When I try to install this nuget I'm getting incompatible error.
What is the way to install EF Core migration tool without the SDK?

Can you please provide a [mre]?

"I need to deploy it with dotnet ef migration tool" - why exactly? do you need the tool itself or just some functionality?

using "code first" approach to db, I have a psql db and DbContext in my project. when the app is starting in my k8s pod it needs to run "dotnet ef database update" command


It needs to run "dotnet ef database update" command

I would recommend a different approach: instead of using tools - use the migrator infrastructure provided by the EF via the IMigrator interface (otherwise it is highly likely you will need the SDK in the pod):
IServiceProvider _serviceProvider = ...;

// ...

// Get the context - AppCtx
var requiredService = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppCtx>();

// Resolve and use migrator:
var migrator = requiredService.GetService<IMigrator>();
await migrator.MigrateAsync(null, stoppingToken);


Thank you! This is a far better approach.
